# Setting up ++ft according to the file extension

Tags: filetype

I have a lot of `*.sage` that follow the Python syntax. However, VIm does not recognize this. Can I make VIm set `++filetype` based solely on the file extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `ftdetect` plugin for vim. Read `:h ftdetect` for detailed information. To quote from the docs for the lazy :

> If a file type that you want to use is not detected yet, there are four ways
>   to add it.  In any way, it's better not to modify the $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim
>   file.  It will be overwritten when installing a new version of Vim.
>
> A. If you want to overrule all default file type checks.
>     This works by writing one file for each filetype.  The disadvantage is that
>     means there can be many files.  The advantage is that you can simply drop
>     this file in the right directory to make it work.
>
> 1. Create your user runtime directory.  You would normally use the first
>       item of the 'runtimepath' option.  Then create the directory "ftdetect"
>       inside it.  Example for Unix:
>
>    ```
>    :!mkdir ~/.vim
>    :!mkdir ~/.vim/ftdetect
>    ```
> 2. Create a file that contains an autocommand to detect the file type.
>       Example:
>
>    ```
>    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.mine      set filetype=mine
>    ```
>
>    Note that there is no "augroup" command, this has already been done
>       when sourcing your file.  You could also use the pattern "*" and then
>       check the contents of the file to recognize it.
>       Write this file as "mine.vim" in the "ftdetect" directory in your user
>       runtime directory.  For example, for Unix:
>
>    ```
>    :w ~/.vim/ftdetect/mine.vim
>    ```
> 3. To use the new filetype detection you must restart Vim.
>      The files in the "ftdetect" directory are used after all the default
>      checks, thus they can overrule a previously detected file type.  But you
>      can also use `:setfiletype` to keep a previously detected filetype.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, using the `au(tocmd)` event handler for events `BufNewFile` and `BufRead`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sage set filetype=python
```