# Open .md files as Markdown

Tags: filetype

Vim, by default, opens all .md files as "modula2" code. I have never heard of modula2, nor do I plan to use it.

How can I tell vim to always treat `foo.md` as Markdown (as if I had typed `:set ft=markdown`)?

Comment: On what distribution is this the case? I am currently running Archlinux and `.md` is being seen as markdown

Comment: @Neikos This is on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: on fedora as well I correctly get markdown syntax on .md files

Comment: [This has already been answered on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14779012/1951857)  You may find more and different information there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up ++ft according to the file extension](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/61/setting-up-ft-according-to-the-file-extension)

Comment: As an aside, I find this plugin very useful for editing markdown https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown

Comment: FYI, as of Vim 7.4.480, `*.md` files are recognized as Markdown instead of modula2 by default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the file `filetype.vim` that is shipped with your distribution you will find a line that looks probably similar to this (on my machine it lives at `/usr/share/vim/vim74`) :

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.md,*.m2,*.mi setf modula2
```

Now, this tells vim to set the filetype as modula2 if your file has such an ending.

To override this behaviour you can put a line like this in your own `.vimrc` (Taken from the Archlinux filetype.vim) :

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.markdown,*.mdown,*.mkd,*.mkdn,*.mdwn,*.md  set ft=markdown
```

**Edit:**

I previously had `setf` as the function to be called, but it seems to be a reserved function for the `filetype.vim` file.

Answer (score 13):

I currently have this line as an ugly hack in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead *.md set ft=markdown
```

I'm still wondering if there's a better way, though.

Comment: this does not work in fedora, it seems the /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim definitions will override this setting

Comment: @guido, I wonder if that depends on when you enable filetype detection? If you add that `autocmd` after `filetype on` (with or without the `plugin` / `indent` flags), I would guess the results are better. Not tested, just speculation.