# Vim not recognizing markdown and tex files

Tags: autocmd, filetype

Here is a sample of my .vimrc, that doesn't do a thing (the autocmd does not work) when I open a .md or .tex file, but works fine for .py files:

```
augroup filetype_python
  autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c I#<esc>
  autocmd FileType python set nu
  autocmd FileType python :iabbrev <buffer> iff if:<left>
  autocmd FileType python :iabbrev <buffer> forr for:<left>
  autocmd FileType python :iabbrev <buffer> while while:<left>
  autocmd BufWritePre,BufRead *.py :normal gg=G
augroup END

augroup filetype_tex
  autocmd FileType tex set nu
augroup END

augroup filetype_markdown
  autocmd FileType markdown onoremap i= :<c-u>execute "normal! ?^==\\+$\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>
  autocmd FileType markdown onoremap i- :<c-u>execute "normal! ?^--\\+$\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>
augroup END
```

As if Vim didn't know about markdown and tex (but it's supposed to, I checked the list of all known FileTypes and they were there)... 
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Vim doesn’t treat `.md` flies as markdown by default. Either rename your files to have `.markdown` extensions, or [tell Vim to treat `.md` files as Markdown](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/221/open-md-files-as-markdown?rq=1).

Comment: See also `:help new-filetype`

Comment: Related: my answers about autocmd and filetypes [one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15019/10604) [two](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15325/using-tabenter-and-filetype-in-the-same-autocmd/15329#15329)

Comment: Actually, it seems that the problem only needed my computer to sleep one night to solve itself on its own. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Oh and maybe adding:let g:tex_flavor="latex"