# Markdown is not highlighted

Tags: filetype-markdown

I am unable to turn on syntax highlighting for Markdown. How do I do it?

Here's my version information:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled May 15 2020 15:48:23)
Included patches: 1-758
```

Here's the relevant part of my vimrc

```
" Highlighting for markdown
autocmd BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown.pandoc
```

```
augroup filetype_markdown
  autocmd FileType markdown onoremap i= :<c-u>execute "normal! ?^==\\+$\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>
  autocmd FileType markdown onoremap i- :<c-u>execute "normal! ?^--\\+$\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>
augroup END
```

Originally, I had just the first block above in my vimrc based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964681/enabling-markdown-highlighting-in-vim

It wasn't working, so I added the second block based on this: [Vim not recognizing markdown and tex files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16717/vim-not-recognizing-markdown-and-tex-files)

Comment: Do you have syntax enabled? Check for `syntax` in `:scriptnames`, or look for `syntax enable`/`syntax on` in your vimrc

Comment: That worked @D.BenKnoble . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on syntax highlighting explicitly:

```
syntax enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Per comment to original post (@D.BenKnoble), I set `:syntax enable`, and the Markdown highlighting worked. Run `:help :syntax` for more details. (Scroll to the top of the help page and read down.) Apparently `:syntax on` has similar but **not identical** behavior.